# Comparing 2 dates not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> ΚΡΑΤΗΣΕΙΣ</title>
<link REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="TEXT/CSS " HREF="style.css">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body class="mybackroundcolor">
    ΑΦΙΞΗ:
    <input type="date" name="date1" id="date1" >
    </br>
    ΑΝΑΧΩΡΗΣΗ:
    <input type="date" name="date2" id="date2" >
    </br>
    <button type="button" onclick="fdate()">Click Me!</button>
<script>function fdate(){
    var k = document.getElementById("date1");
    var l = document.getElementById("date2");
    if(k.getTime() > l.getTime()){
    alert("impossible");}
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anything wrong with my function? I want to covert the dates that are in the form of mm/dd/yyyy into numbers using getTime() and compare them.

Comment: Your variables are elements not dates. Elements don't have a `getTime()` method. Open your browser console and look at the errors thrown

Comment: ohh  god..thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value from input fields are not automatically converted to date objects

```
    var k = document.getElementById("date1"); //k is a string
    var l = document.getElementById("date2"); //l is a string
```

Use `valueAsNumber`

```
    var k = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").valueAsNumber);
    var l = new Date(document.getElementById("date2").valueAsNumber);
```

Answer (score -2):

you shoul take a value to get a date. now you are comparing two html 
inputs . Also I would check if input is actually a date

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title> ΚΡΑΤΗΣΕΙΣ</title>
  <link REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="TEXT/CSS ">
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body class="mybackroundcolor">
  ΑΦΙΞΗ:<input type="date" name="date1" id="date1" ></br>
  ΑΝΑΧΩΡΗΣΗ:<input type="date" name="date2" id="date2" ></br>
  <button type="button" onclick="fdate()">Click Me!</button>
  <script>
function fdate(){
   var k = document.getElementById("date1").value;
   var l = document.getElementById("date2").value;
   console.log(l)
   if (typeof k.getTime === 'function' || typeof l.getTime ===   'function' ) {

     if (k.getTime() > l.getTime())  alert("impossible");


  } else {
    console.log('wrong date')
  }
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```